# JPA archive two tables in a third one

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables, X and Y. I want to archive them in a third, A. Is there a way in Spring Boot without rewriting code? Currently I have duplicate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use @Embedded annotation for this